# React Native Modules Not Working Together

Tags: objective-c, react-native, module

I have a react native application I am building, and for part of it I have implemented my own custom module (in this case a webview). I have it set up and everything works fine, until I render two of the same modules on the same screen.

Once I have had two of the same modules on the same screen, the code in Objective-C which calls the onChange method back to javascript no longer executes and I can longer longer communicate with my module through Javascript.

I've noticed that each instance of my module has a tag or something like that, but I am not sure what I should do to fix this.

**Update**

Basically I have added some code and I can see that the issue is when the new module is added to the screen, it overrides the callbacks for the previous module. Once the new modules leaves the screen, the callbacks in Objective-C are still "focused" on the most recently rendered module...

Might this have something to do with?

```
ReactNative.findNodeHandle(this.refs[WEB_VIEW]);
```

**Edit**

I have been looking over some open source code and I think I have narrowed down the problem. Basically my module consists of a WebView and a WebViewManager. The WebViews are pretty simple and just display the contents of the web and such, and the manager is responsible for controlling their behavior.

When I want to call a method on the module from React Native, I can do so by calling the method on the WebViewManager like this:

```
scrollToTop() {
   RNTWebViewManager.scrollToTop();
}
```

In which the manager will then call the corresponding method in Objective-C. However, it seems that when I have more than one instance of a WebView on screen at a time, the manager doesn't know which instance to call, and resorts to calling the most recent instance that was placed on screen.

In the open source project I see that they do something by passings refs around and getting the specific view tags, which is then used by the manager to call on the correct instance of their WebViews, but I am still trying to figure out how to implement this.

Here is the link below for the project I was looking at:
https://github.com/CRAlpha/react-native-wkwebview

Comment: You need to post some code or no one will be able to help.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not much code to post...

Comment: Well something rather than just explanation. For example, *"I have implemented my own custom module (in this case a webview)."* or *"the code in Objective-C which calls the onChange method back to javascript"* or whatever you mean by this *"I've noticed that each instance of my module has a tag or something like that"*. All of those would be a start.

Comment: Ok I will try and clean it up, once sec.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after quite some time and research I have finally figured out the solution. Basically it has to do with making sure the right component is being called from React Native and Objective-C. For example in your react native component you have a function:

```
executeJavascript(tag,js) {
    RNTWebViewManager.executeJavascript(tag,js);
}
```

And then in your Objective-C implementation of RNTWebViewManager you could have something like this:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(executeJavascript:(nonnull NSNumber *)reactTag with:(NSString *)js)
{
  [self.bridge.uiManager addUIBlock:^(__unused RCTUIManager *uiManager, NSDictionary<NSNumber *, RNWebView *> *viewRegistry) {
    RNWebView *view = viewRegistry[reactTag];
    [view evaluateJavaScript:js completionHandler:^(id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
      if (result == nil) { result = @""; }
      id outputError = (error) ? error.description : @"";
      view.onChange(@{ @"result" : result, @"error": outputError, @"type" : @"javascript" });
    }];
  }];
}
```

Notice how the executeJavascript function takes a tag, that is a reference to the current view you are trying to invoke that method on. So basically all you need to do is pass that tag number whenever you want to perform a method on a specific instance, which you can get like so:

```
getTag() {
  return ReactNative.findNodeHandle(this.refs['RNWebView']);
}
```

Where in this case the ref is 'RNWebView', which would give me back the right tag which I could then use to call the function. Hope I did a decent job of explaining this.